# Cannot access local hosts by name, but can by IP address

Tags: networking, dhclient

I'm new to Ubuntu and a novice in networking. I cannot access the hosts on the local network by name from my freshly installed 13.10 (no GUI) server.
 It is not configured as a DHCP server. I use a Netgear R6300v2 for the DHCP server.

I can SSH to the server by name (unix3) from Winpro7 (192.163.1.3)
from the SSH session:
I can ping to Google.com
I cannot ping to WinPro7
I can ping to 192.168.1.3 (WinPro7)
dhclient is running
ifconfig looks good ?

Here is the log from the SSH session where I tried to obtain all the relevant info

```
    =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2014.02.01 09:49:39 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
Using username "frank".
frank@unix3's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 13.10 (GNU/Linux 3.11.0-15-generic i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Sat Feb  1 09:51:41 EST 2014

  System load:  0.04               Processes:           95
  Usage of /:   1.4% of 120.70GB   Users logged in:     1
  Memory usage: 2%                 IP address for eth0: 192.168.1.22
  Swap usage:   0%

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

Last login: Sat Feb  1 09:51:41 2014 from 192.168.1.3

frank@unix3:~$ ping google.com -c3
PING google.com (74.125.226.227) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lga15s29-in-f3.1e100.net (74.125.226.227): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=50.0 ms
64 bytes from lga15s29-in-f3.1e100.net (74.125.226.227): icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=36.5 ms
64 bytes from lga15s29-in-f3.1e100.net (74.125.226.227): icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=36.0 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2009ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 36.022/40.863/50.033/6.489 ms

frank@unix3:~$ ping WinPro7 -c3
ping: unknown host WinPro7

frank@unix3:~$ ping 192.168.1.3 -c3
PING 192.168.1.3 (192.168.1.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.918 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.467 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.3: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=0.422 ms

--- 192.168.1.3 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.422/0.602/0.918/0.224 ms

frank@unix3:~$ ifconfig /-a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:5d:01:04:3d  
          inet addr:192.168.1.22  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:5dff:fe01:43d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4883 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1848 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:802381 (802.3 KB)  TX bytes:169483 (169.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1664 (1.6 KB)  TX bytes:1664 (1.6 KB)


frank@unix3:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 192.168.1.1

frank@unix3:~$ ps -ef | grep dhclient
root       762     1  0 09:26 ?        00:00:00 dhclient -1 -v -pf /run/dhclient.eth0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases eth0
frank     1581  1445  0 09:49 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto dhclient

frank@unix3:~$ cat  /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases
lease {
  interface "eth0";
  fixed-address 192.168.1.22;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 192.168.1.1;
  option dhcp-lease-time 86400;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.1.1;
  renew 5 2014/01/31 22:14:27;
  rebind 5 2014/01/31 22:14:27;
  expire 5 2014/01/31 22:14:27;
}
lease {
  interface "eth0";
  fixed-address 192.168.1.22;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 192.168.1.1;
  option dhcp-lease-time 86400;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.1.1;
  renew 0 2014/02/02 01:43:44;
  rebind 0 2014/02/02 11:26:27;
  expire 0 2014/02/02 14:26:27;
}

frank@unix3:~$ hostname
unix3

frank@unix3:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive

frank@unix3:~$ sudo netstat -uap
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
udp        0      0 *:bootpc                *:*                                 762/dhclient    
udp        0      0 192.168.1.25:netbios-ns *:*                                 833/nmbd        
udp        0      0 192.168.1.22:netbios-ns *:*                                 833/nmbd        
udp        0      0 *:netbios-ns            *:*                                 833/nmbd        
udp        0      0 192.168.1.2:netbios-dgm *:*                                 833/nmbd        
udp        0      0 192.168.1.2:netbios-dgm *:*                                 833/nmbd        
udp        0      0 *:netbios-dgm           *:*                                 833/nmbd        
udp        0      0 *:28567                 *:*                                 762/dhclient    
udp6       0      0 [::]:32733              [::]:*                              762/dhclient

frank@unix3:~$ exit
logout
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try `ping WinPro7.local -c3`. Your `ping` command is trying to resolve `WinPro7` as an FQDN rather than a local machine inside your LAN.

Comment: result of : ping WinPro7.local was:ping: unknown host WinPro7.local

Comment: Then I would have to assume that the Windows box is not going to be resolvable through a `hostname` but only through an IP.

Comment: The Windows box is accessible by name from other (Windows) systems on the local net. The problem is that no local system is accessible from the Ubuntu system (unix3) and the Ubuntu system is accessible by name from the other local systems

Comment: Why are you using your router as the DNS server? Just wondering.. `resolv.conf` usually pipes back to 127.0.0.1 or specific DNS servers outside your LAN.

Comment: Its convenient, and is designed to handle both DHCP and DNS roles

Answer (score 2):

Open Terminal:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/hosts
```

add `192.168.1.3 WinPro7`

so your computer will know that this is the IP for this hostname

Comment: This would work **unless** the IPs are being assigned by DHCP and subject to change.

Comment: I am looking for dynamic addresses, not static. thanks

Comment: do you know a to set dynamic dns  ? if no just tell me

Comment: use the dhclient and point it at the dhcp server. It you have Network-Manager set up the IPV4(IPV6) to obtain the address. Do not check any other option.

Comment: see this for configuration instruction [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Winbind

   ```
   sudo apt-get install winbind
   ```
2. Add WINS to host resolving configuration

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/nsswitch.conf
   ```

   Add `wins` to hosts line, example:

   ```
   hosts:     files wins dns myhostname mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4
   ```

See [HOWTO: resolve hostnames CORRECTLY](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=391601)

---

Otherway using Avahi

1. Install Avahi DNS configuration tool on Ubuntu machine

   ```
   sudo apt-get install avahi-dnsconfd
   ```
2. Install Apple Bonjour on Windows machine

   http://support.apple.com/downloads/DL999/en_US/BonjourPSSetup.exe

Now check `ping WinPro7.local`

See [Avahi (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_%28software%29) or [its official website](http://avahi.org/).

Comment: Using Avahi looks like a reasonable workaround,but I am looking to get my system to work normally. I am sure that I just need to find out what is not working correctly or is not installed.